# VC++ error - cannot open file "odbccp32.libcomctl32.lib"

Tags: visual-c++, toolbar

```
Compiling...
StdAfx.cpp
Compiling...
MotleyFool.cpp
StockBar.cpp
EditQuote.cpp
MFToolbar.cpp
ReflectionWnd.cpp
Generating Code...
Linking...
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file "odbccp32.libcomctl32.lib"
Error executing link.exe.

MotleyFool.dll - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

am trying to develope a IE toolbar. wit the help of.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/ietoolbartutorial.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
odbccp32.libcomctl32.lib
```

is space missing ?

```
odbccp32.lib comctl32.lib
            ^
```

Comment: no space in between, i just copyed this error message from the error console. :(

Comment: Add the space. It should solve the problem provided the lib path is proper.

Comment: Ya, what he means is your input has a space missing, not the error.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your project has got some bad entries in the libraries part. The ODBC library is actually called **odbc32.lib** (odbccp.dll is the control panel library) and the common controls is called **comctl32.lib**.

Answer (score 0):

Your library search path is not correct. Add the path where these files exist to your library search path. In VS2008, goto Tools->Options , Undser Projects and Solutions select VC++ directories. Then in the combo box select library files and set the proper path.

Comment: i think i dont have the file, where do I get the odbccp32.libcomctl32.lib file ??

Comment: i dont have the spcified file

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using an older Visual C++ Express, where the Platform SDK was not included. You can download it from here:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4377f86d-c913-4b5c-b87e-ef72e5b4e065&displaylang=en